# Web service prestashop

Tags: php, webservice, prestashop

Cuando hago una llamada a webservice api prestashop desde laravel, para editar algún campo de la base de datos, si busco por la id de la tabla, no tengo problema, pero cuando filtro por un campo de la tabla, cuando lo guarda, me da un error de que no le he pasado la id para poder guardar.
Ejemplo filtrando por id producto:

```
        $xml = $webservice->get(['resource' => 'stock_availables?filter[id_product]='.$id.'&display=full']);
        $resources = $xml->children()->children()->children();
        $id2 = intval($resources->id);
        $resources->quantity = $unidades;
        $updateXml = $webservice->edit(['resource' => 'stock_availables' , 'id'=> $id2 , 'putXml' => $xml->asXML()]);
```

Ejemplo filtrando con id de la tabla:

```
        $xml1 = $webservice->get(['resource' => 'stock_availables' , 'id' => $id]);
        $resources1 = $xml1->children()->children();
        $id3 = intval($resources1->id);
        $resources1->quantity = $unidades;
        $updateXml = $webservice->edit(['resource' => 'stock_availables' , 'id'=> $id3 , 'putXml' => $xml1->asXML()]);
```

Gracias de antemano.